# dhtmlx scheduler with conflicting appointment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scheduler, appointment

I'm using dthtml scheduler calender,(with mvc 3)
In this demo tutorial , http://carrental-app.scheduler-net.com/
It is not allowing to book the same car for same timing period for different customers.
(for example:  If I book Dodge Caliber from 1:00 to 2:00 for customer A , I'm not able to book it for customer B for 1:30 to 2.30. Though we cannot book the same car for conflicting time, i want both conflicting appointment to get displayed side by side).

I'm using this scheduler in my project for booking appointment,so it is normal to get conflicting appointments.
Now i want to know how to change this scheduler following ways:
(i)Scheduler calender allows conflicting appointments.
(ii)The conflicting appointments has to be shown side by side

[This is a sample image.
This is how I need two conflicting appointments to appear in scheduler calender.
sample.png (9.83 KiB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIz7q.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Conflicting events can be allowed conditionally with a client-side code
js:

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onEventCollision", function (ev, evs) {
   return false;//allow collision
   //or 
   //return true; to cancel conflicting event
});
```

2)And here display settings for appointments
c#:

```
protected void _ConfigureViews(DHXScheduler scheduler, IEnumerable cars)
{
       //show appointments side-by-side
       scheduler.Config.cascade_event_display = true;

       var units = new TimelineView("Orders", "car_id");
       ...
       //set minimum heigth of event bar
       units.EventDy = units.EventMinDy  = units.Dy - 5;
```